# Adopt regular expression to mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I made regular expression

```
^http[s]?:\/\/[^\/]*\.[a-z]+\/?$
```

which perfectly working 
[link](https://regex101.com/r/EqyMsR/1)

now i am moving it to mysql

```
REGEXP ('^http[s]?:\\/\\/[^\\/]*\\.[a-z]+\\/?$')
```

I had to escape forward slash twice (as i understand it mysql specs)

but still this expression catches much more than it suppose to

What is wrong ?

UPDATE
I did more tests and looks like this particular part not doing anything in Mysql
    REGEXP ('[^/]*')
I assume it suppose to filter out all urls NOT contains forward slash

Comment: it'd help a bit if you'd tell us what you're trying to catch.

Comment: I am trying to catch urls that are main page , for example: https://www.google.com or http://www.google.com/ and not https://www.google.com/mypage or https://www.google.com/yourpage.html

Comment: The number of backslashes depends on the number of layers (eg, PHP, MySQL) that the expressions goes through.  Please provide the context.